# How to create a test class with Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am a beginner in java and wanted to do a test in mockito to see if the method return is correct, how do I do it?
How to mock the call api?
This is the class that I want to test.

```
public class FilmController {
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

public ArrayList<Film> getAll() throws JSONException {
        String res = restTemplate.getForObject("https://copadosfilmes.azurewebsites.net/api/filmes", String.class);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(res);
        ArrayList<Film> films = new ArrayList<Film>(jsonArray.length());
        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
            films.add(new Film(jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("titulo"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("id")));
        }
        return films;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
Mocking the `RestTemplate` object and return different values for `getForObject()`

```
    @Test
    void testFilmController() {
        FilmController c = new FilmController();
        c.restTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
        Mockito.when(c.restTemplate.getForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn("[ { \"jsonField\": \"jsonValue\" }]");
        
        List<Film> expected = Arrays.asList(new Film());
        assertEquals(expected, c.getAll());
    }
```